# Why does a sum-type of `a` containing a list constructor not match a list of `a`?

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to implement [primitive recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function). As apparently it is not common to use variadic functions in Haskell I use a type

```
data PrimT a = Sgl a | Sqc [a]
```

so I can pass atomic values and lists of values to functions. This works alright for the zero function, projection, and the successor function:

```
zero k (Sqc args) = if length args == k then Right 0 else Left "invalid number of arguments"
zero 1 (Sgl arg)  = Right 0

pi i k (Sqc args) = if length args == k then Right $ args!!i else Left "invalid number of arguments"
pi 1 1 (Sgl arg) = Right arg

nu (Sgl i) = Sgl $ i + 1
```

But I am getting problems with composition (here `o`). The idea behind this definition is that composition can happen with a function f and: 1) a list of functions and a list of arguments, 2) a list of functions and one argument, 3) one function and a list of arguments and finally 4) one function and one argument. Therefore I put the functions and in a `PrimT` so I can have cases for `Sqc gs` for a list of functions and `Sgl g` for a single function. Same for the arguments: `Sqc args` and `Sgl arg`.

```
o :: PrimT (PrimT b -> PrimT c) -> PrimT (PrimT a -> PrimT b) -> PrimT a -> PrimT c
o (Sgl f) (Sqc gs) (Sqc args) = f [g args | g <- gs]
-- o (Sgl f) (Sqc gs) (Sgl arg) = f [g arg | g <- gs]
-- o (Sgl f) (Sgl g) (Sqc args) = f [g args]
-- o (Sgl f) (Sgl g) (Sgl arg) = f [g arg]
```

However the compiler is not happy with the part `f [g args | g <- gs]`. It says:

```
primrec.hs:69:35: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘PrimT b’
                  with actual type ‘[PrimT b]’
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘[g args | g <- gs]’
      In the expression: f [g args | g <- gs]
      In an equation for ‘o’:
          o (Sgl f) (Sqc gs) (Sqc args) = f [g args | g <- gs]
    • Relevant bindings include
        gs :: [PrimT a -> PrimT b] (bound at primrec.hs:69:16)
        f :: PrimT b -> PrimT c (bound at primrec.hs:69:8)
        o :: PrimT (PrimT b -> PrimT c)
             -> PrimT (PrimT a -> PrimT b) -> PrimT a -> PrimT c
          (bound at primrec.hs:69:1)
   |
69 | o (Sgl f) (Sqc gs) (Sqc args) = f [g args | g <- gs]
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

primrec.hs:69:38: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘PrimT a’ with actual type ‘[a]’
    • In the first argument of ‘g’, namely ‘args’
      In the expression: g args
      In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘[g args | g <- gs]’
    • Relevant bindings include
        g :: PrimT a -> PrimT b (bound at primrec.hs:69:45)
        args :: [a] (bound at primrec.hs:69:25)
        gs :: [PrimT a -> PrimT b] (bound at primrec.hs:69:16)
        o :: PrimT (PrimT b -> PrimT c)
             -> PrimT (PrimT a -> PrimT b) -> PrimT a -> PrimT c
          (bound at primrec.hs:69:1)
   |
69 | o (Sgl f) (Sqc gs) (Sqc args) = f [g args | g <- gs]
   |
```

But I don't understand why. `PrimT a` can be a list of `a` (`[a]`) according to its definition. So where is the problem?

Comment: `Just 'x'` is not the same as `'x'`. `Char` is not the same type as `Maybe Char`.

Comment: Not helpful without further explanation of what you are referring to.

Comment: fwiw, you're running into all these problems because you're trying to work around the type system. Single values are not the same as lists of values. You can't just use them interchangeably. When you go to work around this by adding a third type, you now have *three* types involved, not two.

Comment: @Carl But it seemed wrong to work with singleton lists for atomic values.

Comment: What is the semantic difference between `Sgl x` and `Sqc [x]`? If none, why do you allow both?

Comment: @DanielWagner I didn't know how to define the list constructor to only contain lists of length >= 2.

Comment: You could write `data PrimT a = Sgl a | Sqc a a [a]` to ensure that there are at least two values in the `Sqc` case. But in such a case I think I'd prefer to use `data PrimT a = PrimT a [a]` or perhaps to just reuse the existing [`NonEmpty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) type. But doesn't primitive recursion also allow 0-ary functions? In which case we're back to my question: why single out 1-ary argument lists as special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `PrimT a` can be a list of `a` (`[a]`) according to its definition

No, `PrimT a` can either be an `Sgl` or an `Sqc`. So given a list `xs` of type `[a]`, `Sqc xs` would be a `PrimT a`, but `xs` would not. `xs` is already a list - it can't also be something else.

By that same logic `Sqc args` is a `PrimT a` and `Sqc [g (Sqc args) | g <- gs]` is a `PrimT (PrimT b)`, but without the `Sqc` they're just lists.

I should also point out that `PrimT (PrimT b)` isn't the type that you want (you want `PrimT b`), so you'll still need to flatten the result to get what you want.

Comment: Okay, so I see why putting `Sqc` in front of the list comprehension is necessary. But I don't understand why it is necessary on fron of `args` inside the function body.

Comment: @lotolmencre We do not have `g :: [a] -> ...` but only `g :: PrimT a -> ...`, so we need to pass a value in the right type.

Comment: @chi But `g` has type `PrimT a -> PrimT b` and args has type `PrimT a`. So... I still don't get it.

Comment: @lotolmencre No, `Sqc args` has type `PrimT a`, `args` has type `[a]`.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I get it.. kind of; I am still getting an error for `o (Sgl f) (Sqc gs) (Sqc args) = f $ Sqc [g (Sqc args) | g <- gs]` which I still don't see why. `Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘PrimT b’` `Expected type: PrimT b
        Actual type: PrimT (PrimT b)`. Why is that now? Apparently `Sqc [...]` is producing a `PrimT (PrimT b)`? Or where does that come from?

Comment: @lotolmencre `Sqc [SomeType]` has type `PrimT SomeType`. `[g (Sqc args) | g <- gs]` has type `[PrimT b]`, so `SomeType` is `PrimT b` in this case and `Sqc [g (Sqc args) | g <- gs]` has type `PrimT (PrimT b)`.